# Getting volley response in another class

Tags: java, android

I made the first request successfully and I like to access my Volley response in other class , how can I do that because when I try to do that it return a null response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use interface and callback

```
public interface RestCallBack {

    void onStart(String action);

    void onComplete(String response, String action,Exception e);
}
```

And in your onResponse

```
 listener.onComplete(response, action, null);
```

Then you can implement this interface in any class where you want the response.

Answer (score 0):

At first its depends on your json data formate .......

1. You need to create a class
2. Declare a method in your class with a parameter string or array and call this method where you get json response

or follow this code

```
public class MyJsonParser {
public  static  Vector<MyModel> getJsonResponse(Context context,String response)
throws JSONException, IOException
{

final JSONObject stringResponse = new JSONObject(response);
final JSONObject responseHolder = stringResponse.getJSONObject("data"); 
  final JSONArray jsonArray = responseHolder .getJSONArray("arrayData");

MyModel myModel;
Vector<MyModel> myArray = new Vector<MyModel>();
for (int i= 0;i<jsonArray .length();i++){
    myModel= new MyModel();
    JSONObject propertyHolder = jsonArray .getJSONObject(i);
    myModel.setId(propertyHolder,"id");
    myModel.setName(propertyHolder, "name");
    myArray .addElement(myModel);
    myModel= null;
}
return myArray ;
}


   }
```

and call this method where you get json response like this....

```
  MyJsonParser.getJsonResponse(context,response);
```